# C# refactore operator as

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have code

```
private IEnumerable<ViewType> GetFilteredList(bool isOnlyChecked, bool IsOnlyUnreaded, bool IsOnlyNotEmpty)
{
    var emptyItems = GetEmptyItems(Data);
    IEnumerable<ViewType> filtered = IsOnlyNotEmpty 
        ? Data
          .Where(key => !emptyItems
              .Any(inner => (inner as View<InformServiceView, InformServiceBriefInfo>).Source.Id == (key as View<InformServiceView, InformServiceBriefInfo>).Source.Id))
          .ToList() 
        : Data;
    filtered = IsOnlyChecked ? GetAllChecked(filtered) : filtered;
    filtered = IsOnlyUnreaded ? GetAllUnReaded(filtered) : filtered;
    filtered = filtered.Where(FullTextSearch.SearchPredicate<ViewType>(FilterString ?? string.Empty));
    return filtered;
}
```

what is the best wat to refactore to looong line of code

```
IEnumerable<ViewType> filtered = IsOnlyNotEmpty ? Data.Where(key => !emptyItems.Any(inner => (inner as View<InformServiceView, InformServiceBriefInfo>).Source.Id == (key as View<InformServiceView, InformServiceBriefInfo>).Source.Id)).ToList() : Data;
```

Comment: This question better fits to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @diiN_, I forecast that my question there will be closed in few minutes marked with "pseudocode".